# How to extract features from ROIs of palmprint?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I am working on palmprint authentication, i have captured the palm images and have done the preprocessing and the ROI extraction.
Now i have to extract features from the ROI such as 'principle lines' and then later use this for matching.
 
So how do i extract these features and find accuracy of matching using these features? Any suggestion or the code regarding this shall be appreciated.

[Captured palm image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXVHS.jpg)

[ROI of palm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kcfY.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the features which you are looking for? For example. How do you define a principle line? and which other features do you need?

Comment: http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/17745/media/image2.png

Comment: The above image show the principle lines..

Comment: you should start with a better image first. your imaging is not very suitable for that task. at least improve your illumination or try something like photometric stereo

Answer (score 0):

You have to enhance principal edges ; you can use firangi filter which is very good at this job
here is link to get code

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter/content/FrangiFilter2D.m

I have tried it on you image here is results
[image]

you can change options to get more refined results .I would like to mention that this is just extraction /enhancement of edges not features .I presume that this is your requirement.If you want feature extraction from your palm image i would suggest use

> **'local binary pattern'**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns